# How do you visit your main ember app when running "ember test --serve" with ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Usually, when I run my ember app with "ember serve", I can visit localhost:4200 and see my web page. However, when I want to run tests with "ember test --serve", I can only visit the test page at localhost:7357.

Is there a way to visit my full ember web page when I run "ember test --serve" without having to simultaneously run "ember serve"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way around: while running normally with `ember serve` (in development mode) simply visit http://localhost:4200/tests and you'll be running the same tests. You don't get the same test control through the console though.

Comment: Just note if you visit `/tests` your environment will be `development` not `test`.